# How to simulate a ServiceBusProcessor instance for unit testing in C#

Tags: c#, azureservicebus

I am relatively new to service bus and understanding it. I recently created a class that serves the single purpose of processing messages and ingesting them as they come via service bus and some other entities (others unrelated).

Although my code works, the pain is unit testing and mocking service bus processor. I initialize my StartAsync method, create my processor, but I have no idea how to test the handlers. My goal is to somehow create a processor mock that simulates a new process event arg entering that processor and then does some internal logic. Code below explains more.

```
public class MyTest()
{
        public MyTest(servicebusbuilder, etc) { stuff }
        public async Task StartAsync()
        {
            serviceBusclient = serviceBusBuilder.CreateClient(config);

            // Create service bus message processor.
            processor = serviceBusclient.CreateProcessor(
                "test",
                "mytest",
                new ServiceBusProcessorOptions()
                {
                    not relevant...
                });

            processor.ProcessMessageAsync += async (args) =>
            {
                // internal service logic
                // read and clean message, do something with it
                // what I want to test with a test args value of my choosing

                // Complete the message. message is deleted from the subscription queue.
                await args.CompleteMessageAsync(args.Message);
            };

            processor.ProcessErrorAsync += (args) =>
            {
                // log error from args info

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };

            // Create some other dependency
            ...

            // Start receiving message.
            await processor.StartProcessingAsync();
        }
}
```

The process gets started by calling the constructor, then running MyTest.StartAsync() which just does its own thing until dispose/stop/cancel time (calling MyTest.StopAsync()).

For unit testing, I really wanted to have servicebusclient return a mock processor that lets me simulate a ProcessMessageEventArgs object coming into a self defined or mocked Processor object and then the existing ProcessMessageAsync() Handler performing service logic on it. I have already gotten far enough to create a chain of mocks where service bus builder returns client which can return some kind of controllable ServiceBusProcessor.

Sadly I am really new to Service Bus. I have seen a lot of reference info which I will include here in hopes that someone can help me put two and two together. What I tried can be found in the supporting info but I will add a tidbit of my ideal unit test also.

References that seem great but I can't connect the dots:

[open thread on git](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/35660)

[Test at Line 322](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/tests/Processor/ProcessorTests.cs)

[Another Sample Test](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/samples/Sample15_MockingClientTypes.md#simulating-the-processor-running)
I think this doesn't work for me because I need to dispatch my message to an internal handler with StartAsync, not testing the handler externally.

By the way, if people have suggestions to alter my code structure in a better way, I am open to suggestion. However, I still want a solution to this exact scenario if possible. Idc if I gotta use reflection on the sample Mock Processor or some other dark magic. I'm just invested in seeing this specific scenario work out now lol (curiosity and pride).

```
        [TestMethod]
        public async Task MyTester()
        {
            var mockReceiver = new Mock<ServiceBusReceiver>();

            mockReceiver.Setup(r => r.FullyQualifiedNamespace).Returns("namespace");
            mockReceiver.Setup(r => r.EntityPath).Returns("entityPath");

            var message = ServiceBusModelFactory.ServiceBusReceivedMessage(messageId: "1");
            var processArgs = new ProcessMessageEventArgs(
                message,
                mockReceiver.Object,
                CancellationToken.None);

            var mockProcessor = new MockProcessor();

            mockServiceBusClient = new Mock<ServiceBusClient>();

            mockServiceBusClient
                .Setup(x => x.CreateProcessor(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<ServiceBusProcessorOptions>()))
                .Returns(mockProcessor)
                .Verifiable();

            mockServiceBusBuilder = new Mock<ServiceBusBuilder>();

            mockServiceBusBuilder
                .Setup(x => x.CreateClient(It.IsAny<NetStateWatcherConfig>()))
                .Returns(mockServiceBusClient.Object)
                .Verifiable();           

            var myTest = new MyTest(
                mockServiceBusBuilder.Object,
                stopEvent);

            // crux of what I want, simulate processor getting a message and then my application code in the ProcessMessageAsync Handler within myTest.StartAsync() actually running and doing whatever its supposed to do
            // I don't want to mock the handler, I want to simulate a message coming in and the handler running
            await mockProcessor.OnProcessMessageAsyncHelper(processArgs);

            await myTest.StartAsync();

            await myTest.StopAsync();

            // Run some mock verify exactly x times stuff for things mocked within the handler (not an issue), see if processeventargs got changed etc etc to test, not relevant
        }

... outside and under test class

#pragma warning disable SA1402 // File may only contain a single type
    /// <summary>
    /// Mock Service Bus Processor Object.
    /// </summary>
    internal class MockProcessor : ServiceBusProcessor
#pragma warning restore SA1402 // File may only contain a single type
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="MockProcessor"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public MockProcessor()
            : base()
        {
        }

        // Could not access my own override method directly because protected so I tried making it public; It was originally protected internal but that causes issue w C# compiler for modifier vs overriden method which is also protected internal virtual
        // running the UT above gives me a "FullyQualifiedNameSpace" is null error
        public async Task OnProcessMessageAsyncHelper(ProcessMessageEventArgs args)
        {
            await base.OnProcessMessageAsync(args);
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Overrided message handler.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">Sample message.</param>
        /// <returns>Task to complete.</returns>
        protected override async Task OnProcessMessageAsync(ProcessMessageEventArgs args)
        {
            await base.OnProcessMessageAsync(args);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Overrided message handler.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">Sample message.</param>
        /// <returns>Task to complete.</returns>
        protected override async Task OnProcessErrorAsync(ProcessErrorEventArgs args)
        {
            await base.OnProcessErrorAsync(args);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the description, it seems that you want to test your processing logic, both in the handler and in the classes that the handlers delegate to.   The processor guarantees that your handlers will be called at the appropriate time and with the appropriate data.   Can you help us understand why you're trying to mock the entire processor to do so?

Comment: I want to test the handler logic within StartAsync. If I can avoid doing some crazy mocking that would be cool. Based on that I am guessing my two options are this -> 
1) can sending in a message be done with either a mock or new processor object? 2) if not, should I separate my handler to another method or something and test it separately and what would be an example of that (rather new to c# as a language also).

Comment: There is no handler logic in StartAsync related to your code - from that statement, it sounds like you're wanting to test the SDK.  We can trust that StartAsync does it's job and invokes your handlers.  It makes sense to validate that you call it when you think you do or that you'd want to validate that you assign the handlers you think that you assign, both of which can be done without mocking the internals of the processor.   If you need to simulate the processor running, such as for an integration test looking at end-to-end flow, the last sample that you linked to accomplishes that.